# Sending data from UIViewController to UITableViewController and return it back in Swift

Tags: uitableview, uiviewcontroller, swift, ios8

I have `UIViewController` with embedded `NavigationController` (CurrentCityViewController.swift) which sends data in UITableViewController (CitiesListTableViewController.swift). This is part of code in `UIViewController`:

```
......
var currentCityIndex: Int = 0
var resultWeatherArray: [(city:String, country:String, image:UIImage, weather:String, temp:String, humidity:String, wind:String, windspeed:String, pressure:String)] = []
var isFirstStart: Bool = true

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    if isFirstStart == true {
        println("First start")
        isFirstStart = false
        ......
    }
    else {
        println("Not first start")
        println("Received index: \(currentCityIndex)")
        localCityName.text = resultWeatherArray[currentCityIndex].city
        ......
    }
}

......

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {

    if segue.identifier? == "showFavCities" {
        let destViewController:CitiesListTableViewController! = segue.destinationViewController as CitiesListTableViewController
        destViewController.resultWeatherArray = self.resultWeatherArray
    }
}
```

In `UITableViewController` I choose the row. Next, I want to pass the row number back to UIViewController and use that number. But! String `println("Received index: \(currentCityIndex)")` in `UIViewController` always display 0! This is part of code the `UITableViewController`:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    currentCityController.currentCityIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow().row
    println("Index for send: \(currentCityController.currentCityIndex)")
    self.navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

For example, I choose the second row in the table in `UITableViewController`. `println("Index for send: \(currentCityController.currentCityIndex)")` displayed 1. But, in `UIViewController` line `println("Received index: \(currentCityIndex)")` displayed 0!

Why? What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved! In `UITableViewController`:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    var currentCityController = self.navigationController.viewControllers[0] as CurrentCityViewController
    currentCityController.currentCityIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow().row
    self.navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```